# How to enable a children of a clone object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clone, children

I hold my clones in a list for GUI operations in Unity3D & C#.

```c#
button = Instantiate(BlackBox, Vector2.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
buttons.Add(button);
```

How to enable ArrowRight in [this situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faoSl.png)?

I want to reach ArrowRight to enable it. I tried variations of this kind of methods:

```c#
buttons[index].gameObject.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

but it doesn't work. [Objects' components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cnYI.png).

Comment: Looking at the image, I suspect that you want to call GetChild(0), but that's a minor issue. Another doubt: is the BlackBox object itself activated? Because you cannot make a child active if the parent's not.

Comment: Yes, but this code does not enable ArrowLeft too.

Comment: You are right, I have edited my comment with another issue while you were answering back :)

Comment: BlackBox is activated.

Comment: If this is c# don't tag it unityscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

instead of:

```
buttons[index].gameObject.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

use:

```
buttons[index].transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

Comment: You do realize that both of those are the exact same thing right? One is only going through one extra step to get the transform of the gameobject.

Comment: I don't know, one of them doesn't work, one of them does. I am a beginner on Unity and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I just quickly got this code to fix your issue. Maybe not the best solution but it should work if I understood your question correctly.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class blackBox : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool toggleRight;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(toggleRight)
        {
            foreach(Transform child in transform)
            {
                if(child.name.Equals("ArrowRight"))
                {
                    child.gameObject.SetActive(!child.gameObject.activeSelf);
                }
            }
            toggleRight = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a demo, rip it up to suite your needs.

Place that on the blackbox gameobject and well use the foreach to activate or deactivate the gameobject with said name.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't work. I change your code this way:
`foreach(Transform child in buttons[index].transform)
            {
                if(child.name.Equals("ArrowRight"))
                {
                    child.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                }
            }`

Comment: Well yeah, if you dont want to check the gameobjects children thatd be how to do it. As i said "rip it up to suite your needs". Did it do what you wanted in the end though?

Comment: My changes doesn't work too. I just typed how I modify your code while trying. But the answer has finded: buttons[index].transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);